# Symfony2 - custom Validation not firing up

Tags: php, symfony

I have a form with multiple date fields. I need to check if `eventStop` < `eventStart` (date fields). IF it's true, `$form->isValid()` should stop script and put errors on page.
So according to
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html#constraint-validators-with-dependencies
I've create new custom validation constraint but when I submit the form, my validation is not execute, script skips it...

My code:
MyBundle\Validator\Constraints\EventFormFieldsValidator.php

```
namespace MyBundle\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

/**
 * @Annotation
 */
class EventFormFieldsValidator extends ConstraintValidator {

    private $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $em) {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function validate($object, Constraint $constraint) {
        die('end'); /* just for check  */
        $this->context->addViolationAt('eventStart', 'There is already an event during this time!');
        $this->context->addViolation('There is already an event during this time!');
    }

}
```

MyBundle\Validator\Constraints\EventFormFields.php

```
namespace MyBundle\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;

/**
 * @Annotation
 */
class EventFormFields extends Constraint {

    public function validatedBy() {
        return 'event_form_validator';
    }

    public function getTargets() {
        return self::CLASS_CONSTRAINT;
    }

}
```

MyBundle\Entity\Event.php

```
namespace MyBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use MyBundle\Validator\Constraints as ValidateAssert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="MyBundle\Entity\EventRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="events")
 * @ValidateAssert\EventFormFields
 * 
 */
class Event {
    ....
```

MyBundle\Resources\config\services.yml

```
services:
    validator.unique.my_form_validator:
        class: MyBundle\Validator\Constraints\EventFormFieldValidator
        arguments:
            - "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"
        tags:
            - { name: validator.constraint_validator, alias: event_form_validator }
```

app\Resources\config\services.yml

```
imports:
    - { resource: "@MyBundle/Resources/config/services.yml" }
```

MyBundle\Forms\EventFormType.php

```
namespace MyBundle\Forms;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;


class EventFormType extends AbstractType {

    public function getName() {
        return 'c_event';
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder
                ->add('eventName', 'text', array(
                    'label' => 'Event name',
                    'attr'=> array('class'=>'input-sm')
                ))
                ->add('location', 'text', array(
                    'label' => 'Location',
                    'attr'=> array('class'=>'input-sm')
                ))
                ->add('description', 'textarea', array(
                    'label' => 'Description',
                    'attr'=> array('class'=>'input-sm')
                ))
                ->add('eventStart','collot_datetime', array(
                    'label' => 'Event start',
                    'attr'=> array('class'=>'input-sm'),
                    'pickerOptions' => [
                        'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii:00',
                        'weekStart' => 1,
                        'autoclose' => true,
                        'keyboardNavigation' => true,
                        'language' => 'en',
                        'minuteStep' => 5,
                        'pickerReferer ' => 'default', //deprecated
                        'pickerPosition' => 'bottom-right',
                    ]
                ))
                ->add('eventStop','collot_datetime', array(
                    'label' => 'Event end',
                    'attr'=> array('class'=>'input-sm'),
                    'pickerOptions' => [
                        'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii:00',
                        'weekStart' => 1,
                        'autoclose' => true,
                        'keyboardNavigation' => true,
                        'language' => 'en',
                        'minuteStep' => 5,
                        'pickerReferer ' => 'default', //deprecated
                        'pickerPosition' => 'bottom-right',
                    ]
                ))
                ->add('eventSignUpEndDate','collot_datetime', array(
                    'label' => 'Sign up until',
                    'attr'=> array('class'=>'input-sm'),
                    'pickerOptions' => [
                        'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii:00',
                        'weekStart' => 1,
                        'autoclose' => true,
                        'keyboardNavigation' => true,
                        'language' => 'en',
                        'minuteStep' => 5,
                        'pickerReferer ' => 'default', //deprecated
                        'pickerPosition' => 'bottom-right',
                    ]
                ))
                ->add('maxGuests','integer', array(
                    'label' => 'Max guests',
                    'required' => false,
                    'attr'=> array(
                                'placeholder'   => 'Empty for unlimited',
                                'class' => 'input-sm'
                            )
                ))
                ->add('latitude','text', array(
                    'label' => 'Latitude',
                    'attr'=> array(
                            'class'=>'input-sm',
                        )
                ))
                ->add('longitude','text', array(
                    'label' => 'Longitude',
                    'attr'=> array(
                            'class'=>'input-sm',
                        )
                ))
                ->add('private','checkbox', array(
                        'label'    => 'Private',
                        'required' => false,
                ));
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(\Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'MyBundle\Entity\Event',
            'validation_groups' => array('registration'),
        ));
    }

}
```

Comment: What does your form type look like ?

Comment: @GrégoryElhaimer I've just updated my post.

Comment: OK, i don't know why but today it works perfect.. :|

Comment: Probably a cache issue then.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the validation group in the validation definition as follow:

MyBundle\Entity\Event.php

```
namespace MyBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use MyBundle\Validator\Constraints as ValidateAssert;

    /**
     * @ORM\Entity
     * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="MyBundle\Entity\EventRepository")
     * @ORM\Table(name="events")
     * @ValidateAssert\EventFormFields(groups={"registration"})
     * 
     */
    class Event {
```

Hope this help

Comment: Attempted to load class "EventFormField" from namespace "MyBundle\Validator\Constraints".
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?
Should i remove `'validation_groups' => array('registration'),` from EventFormType.php?

Comment: sorry @breq i only paste your code... in practice you must specify to the custom validator the validation group. In the code i pasted there is a `s` at the end of `EventFormFields`

Comment: @breq of course, if you want to investigate about the validation groups you can remove the validation groups directive from the formtype

Comment: OK, so I have removed `validation_groups' => array('registration')` from form, next change `Event` class from `@ValidateAssert\EventFormFields` to `@ValidateAssert\EventFormFields(groups={"EventFormFields"})` but it still not working.. Just skipping my validation

Comment: @breq sorry if you remove the validation group from the form type DON'T specify it in the validator